# solve mathematical equation with 1 unknown (equations are dynamically built)

Tags: equation, math

I have to built dynamically equations like following:

x + x/3 + (x/3)/4 + (x/3/4)/2 = 50

Now I would like to evaluate this equation and get x. The equation is built dynamically. x is the leaf node in a taxonomy, the other 3 nodes are the super concepts. The divisor represents the number of children of the child nodes.

Is there a library that allows to build such equations dynamically and resolve x?

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your equations always of this form (linear in x)?
If so, when building the equation, just set x to 1 and evaluate the lhs.
This will give you lhs = 1 + 1/3 + (1/3)/4 + (1/3/4)/2 = 1.4583..
Then calculate x = rhs / lhs = 50 / 1.4583

Comment: yes they are always in this form! is there a java library handling this? THANKS

Answer (score 1):

It might help you to do some algebra on it.

Note that:

```
x= 3*x/3 = (x*4*3*2)/(4*3*2)
x+x/3 = 3x/3 + x/3 = 4x/3
```

and in your particular case:

```
x + x/3 + (x/3)/4 + (x/3/4)/2 = (x*4*3*2)/(4*3*2) + (x*4*2)/(4*3*2) + (x*2)/(4*3*2) + (x)/(4*3*2) 
= (4*3*2x + 4*2x + 2*x + x)/(4*3*2)
```

Perhaps if you can find a way to have the left hand side rewritten as a single big fraction like this, the solution will come much easier.
Also, factor out the x

```
(4*3*2x + 4*2x + 2*x + x)/(4*3*2) = x*(4*3*2 + 4*2 + 2 + 1)/(4*3*2)
```

Then solve for x

```
50= x*(a/b)
50*(b/a) = x
```

Since you have some code generating the polynomial, you should be able to generate this big (a/b) fraction thing pretty easily too.  I purposely did not simplify the multiplications so that it is clear where each component comes from.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to use Java, you can try [JAS](http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/). It claims to be able to solve polynomials equations.

FTA:

> The Java Algebra System
>   (JAS) is an object oriented, type safe
>   and multi-threaded approach to
>   computer algebra. JAS provides a well
>   designed software library using
>   generic types for algebraic
>   computations implemented in the Java
>   programming language. The library can
>   be used as any other Java software
>   package or it can be used
>   interactively or interpreted through
>   an jython (Java Python) front end. The
>   focus of JAS is at the moment on
>   commutative and solvable polynomials,
>   Groebner bases and applications. By
>   the use of Java as implementation
>   language JAS is 64-bit and multi-core
>   cpu ready.